# Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum possible value for $x_1x_2 · · · x_n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $x_1, . . . , x_n$ be nonnegative real numbers, and suppose that
$x_1 + · · · + x_n = c$, where *c* is a fixed positive constant.

Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum possible value for $x_1x_2 · · · x_n$ in terms of *c*
and *n*.

I haven't had much exposure to Lagrange multipliers. How would I use the Lagrange function to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Optimize 
$$f(\vec x) = \prod_{k=1}^nx_k $$
Subject to the constraint
$$ G(\vec x) = \sum_{k=1}^nx_k =c   $$

The idea is that the constrained max must occur where $\vec \nabla f  \parallel \vec \nabla g  $ because $\vec \nabla g  $  is the only direction that $\vec \nabla f  $ can have while all directional derivatives vanish on the $n-1$ dimensional surface defined by the constraint.

In this case looking at the $p^{th}$ components ...

$$  \left(  \vec \nabla g \right)_p=1  $$

$$  \left(  \vec \nabla f \right)_p= \frac{\prod_{k=1}^nx_k }{x_p}  $$

clearly all the components of $ \vec \nabla f $ must be equal

so $x_p = \frac cn$

and the optimal value of $f$ constrained to $g$ is $\left( \frac {c}{n} \right)^n$

Comment: Ok that is interesting. So that optimal value is the maximum?

Comment: yes, provided $c $ is positive

Comment: Okay and how would I show that that is in fact the maximum by discussing the boundary?

Comment: @JackHarold what boundary are you referring to ?

Comment: Like what happens at the boundary that proves that it is in fact a maximum?